# youtube cast_sender.js errors greatly undermining my page performance

Tags: javascript, performance, chromecast, jssor

Whenever you have an embedded youtube iframe on your page, you keep getting cast_sender errors on your console. According to some other questions on SO, this is because the embedded codes repeatedly try to communicate with some non-exist extension by ajax.

Normally, I wouldn't mind this as long as my users don't see the errors. But on this page I am using youtube iframes as slideshows with transition effects. The transition effects perform well normally, but when the cast_sender is acting up, the transition is greatly affected and goes very slowly.

That is to say, if you have multiple youtube iframes on your page, its performance could be greatly undermined by the cast_sender bug. It seems to me currently there is no fix to this bug, I'm just wondering how everyone is dealing with this issue, especially when they have many youtube iframes on their page.